# is the order of tables relevant when importing from oracle dump?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, dump, imp

I am trying to import specific tables from an oracle dump, in order to avoid any parent key not found exception, I want to follow a certain order to import the tables. For example if tables X depends on tables A and B, I want to import A and B first:

```
imp user/pass@dbName tables=(A,B,X) rows=y ignore=Y
```

Will this command guarantee that A and B are imported before X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
exp userid=ronr tables=COMM_SCHEDULE_DELIVERY,COMM_SCHEDULE_DETAIL,COMM_SCHEDULE_HEADER file=z.dmp
...
...

imp userid=imp fromuser=ronr touser=imp tables=COMM_SCHEDULE_HEADER,COMM_SCHEDULE_DETAIL,COMM_SCHEDULE_DELIVERY file=z.dmp
Import: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Tue Aug 7 16:53:34 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Password: 

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Tes

Export file created by EXPORT:V11.02.00 via conventional path

Warning: the objects were exported by RONR, not by you

import done in US7ASCII character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible charset conversion)
. importing RONR's objects into IMP
. . importing table       "COMM_SCHEDULE_DELIVERY"          0 rows imported
. . importing table         "COMM_SCHEDULE_DETAIL"          0 rows imported
. . importing table         "COMM_SCHEDULE_HEADER"          0 rows imported
Import terminated successfully without warnings.
```

No, the order specified on imp does not guarantee the order in which the tables are imported, it is done in the order in which they are exported.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination!

Comment: That's a shame to ignore import order. I need to load each table separately as originally I don't care about export order ((